# facebook app can't run in a local environment

Tags: facebook

I search through the net and all I found were instructions 1 year ago. I was wondering since all of those suggestions weren't working for me, how could I make my app run in facebook using local environment. I tried using localhost as domain and app on canvas url, used "127.0.0.1" but this returns invalid domain and "cannot be facebook url". I tried using my ip address but the app still won't run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

[image: Describing setup of facebook app for local development]

from http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app

I only have the following set and it works with local development

```
Display Name: WebsiteName
namespace:mynamespace
Contact Email: myemail@me.com
Canvas URL: http://localhost:49166/
```

Comment: the port num should really be 49166? i tried using 80 and that but it still doesn't work? I'm thinkning that the error's in the port number

Comment: If you run your site locally, what port number does it show in the browser? Use that one! If you are running on port 80 it should work to just type localhost. Facebook checks to see whaterver you domain is in yur browser so again, use that one.